# Mysql Select query to get data from three table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three table like below
Table name : word

```
+----+----------+--------+------------+--------+
| id | word     | letter | origin     |literal |
+----+----------+--------+------------+------------+----+
| 7  | അകക്കരപ്പന്‍ | അ      | അകം1-കരപ്പന്‍ |bc  |
+----+----------+--------+-------------------------+----+
| 8  | അകക്കഴി   | അ      | അകം1-കഴി   |af    |
+----+----------+--------+-----------------------+-----+
```

Table name: relation

```
+----+---------+---------------+-------+
| id | id_word | id_definition | rtype |
+----+---------+---------------+-------+
| 6  | 4       | 6             | നാ.   |
+----+---------+---------------+-------+
| 7  | 5       | 7             | നാ.   |
+----+---------+---------------+-------+
```

Table name: definition

```
+----+------------+
| id | definition |
+----+------------+
| 1  | ചായ        |
+----+------------+
| 2  | ചായച്ചെടി   |
+----+------------+
```

I need literal, origin, rtype, definition from these table. I used following query,

```
SELECT
    literal,
    origin,
    rtype,
    word.id,
    definition,
    id_definition
from definition, relation, word
WHERE
    word = '$wpm' AND
    relation.id_word = word.id AND
    definition.id = id_definition
```

But don't get ant result. Please give me the correct query.

Comment: What does $wpm contain? Are you sure there's anything to fetch?

Comment: Look up the `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: It is user input that should match column name `word` in table `word`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several problems with your query, most notable that you are using the now deprecated old school join syntax, and also that your join conditions are not well defined.  I suggest the following:

```
SELECT
    w.literal,
    w.origin,
    r.rtype,
    w.id,
    d.definition,
    r.id_definition
FROM word w
INNER JOIN relation r
    ON w.id = r.id_word
INNER JOIN definition d
    ON r.id_definition = d.id
WHERE
    w.word = ?;
```

Note that I leave the value of `word` in the `WHERE` clause as a placeholder `?`.  You should read about prepared statements in PHP, which will explain what this means and how you should handle/implement it in your PHP code.